# How do I access getBlocksWithLimit with web3 JavaScript API?

Tags: rpc, web3.js

How can I access `getBlocksWithLimit` method using **Solana-web3.js** ?

When I try to access using the following method:

```
let get_blocks_with_limit = await connection.getBlocksWithLimit(start_slot,1);
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: connection.getBlocksWithLimit is not a function
```

I cant find its defnation in Web3.js file source code either.

Answer (score 1):

`getBlocksWithLimit` hasn't been added to web3.js yet. PRs are welcome though!

You can probably just copy the `getBlocks` implementation, change the second parameter name to `limit`, and rename the underlying RPC call to `getBlocksWithLimit`.

Here's the implementation for reference https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/8c47e2168e462e935b87b856b28bc9ba7ed76628/web3.js/src/connection.ts#L4932-L4947